# Quicksort implement in Python run with none stop

Tags: python, quicksort

This is my quicksort algorithms. Very simple

```
x = 0
def swap(list, a, b):
    temp = list[a]
    list[a] = list[b]
    list[b] = temp
    return list
def quicksort2(list, left, right):
    if right > left:
        global x
        x = x + 1
        print x , list, left, right
        l = left+1
        r = right
        while l <= r :
            while list[l] < list[left]:
                l = l + 1
            while list[r] > list[left]:
                r = r - 1
            if l < r:
                list = swap(list, l, r)
        list = swap(list, left, r)
        list = quicksort2(list, left, r-1);
        return quicksort2(list, r+1, right);
    return list
```

But when i run my testcase

```
b = list([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 6, 32])
quicksort2(b, 0, len(b)-1)
```

the result is

```
1 [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 6, 32] 0 9
2 [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 6, 32] 1 9
```

and stop at this...
Anybody have any reason ...

Comment: Your attempt is not very simple, you might wanna just look here: http://en.literateprograms.org/Quicksort_(Python) Your code is very over complicated

Comment: on a side note, `list[a], list[b] = list[b], list[a]` is the pythonic way of doing swaps

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to trace the program execution under a debugger...?

The `while l <= r` loop runs forever, because after several decrements of `r`

- `left == 1`
- `l == 2`
- `r == 2`

and

- `l` is not incremented, because `list[2]` is not less than `list[1]`
- `r` is not decremented any longer, because `list[2]` is not greater than `list[1]`
- no swap is done, because `l` is not less than `r`
- and loop will continue, because `l` is still equal to `r`.......

Answer (score 0):

I simply modified your code a bit.. Found several mistakes, some already mentioned by others. The rest I am not going to go through.
However, you do not have to return a modified list, as lists in python are always passed by reference.

This should be working:

```
def quicksort2(list, low, high):
    global x
    x = x + 1
    print x , list, low, high

    l = low
    r = high
    mid = list[(r + l) / 2]
    while l <= r:
      while list[l] < mid: l += 1
      while list[r] > mid: r -= 1
      if l <= r:
        list[l], list[r] = list[r], list[l] #swap(r,l)
        l += 1
        r -= 1

    if r > low: quicksort2(list, low, r);
    if l < high: quicksort2(list, l, high);


if __name__ == '__main__':
  x = 0
  b = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 6, 32]
  quicksort2(b, 0, len(b)-1)
  print b
```